# How to set nested associated Models

Tags: php, activerecord, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I'm trying to understand how to create nested data with `CakePHP` and `saveAssociated` method without success, I've wrote a model structure where a `Character` > `hasMany` > `PropertyGroup` and a `PropertyGroup` > `hasMany` >`Property`.

How can I create a relation between PropertyGroup and it's Properties in the add view?

```
// Character Model
echo $this->Form->input('name', array ('label' => false, 'value' => 'Character name'));
echo $this->Form->input('description', array ('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => false, 'value' => 'Character description'));
// PropertyGroup Model
echo $this->Form->input('PropertyGroup.0.name', array ('label' => false, 'value' => 'Group name'));
echo $this->Form->input('Property.0.name', array ('label' => false, 'value' => 'Property name'));
echo $this->Form->input('Property.0.value', array ('label' => false, 'value' => 'Property value'));

echo $this->Form->end('Add character');
```

My problem starts if I'd like to create multiple `PropertyGroups`, so:

```
PropertyGroup.0.name
    Property.0.name
    Property.0.value
    Property.1.name
    Property.1.value

PropertyGroup.1.name
    Property.0.name
    Property.0.value
    Property.1.name
    Property.1.value
```

How can I set the form to be compatible to multiple `PropertyGroups`?

I can do it via javascript to like cloning via jQuery the inputs I need and incrementing the id, but I'm not sure how can I do it with `Properties`.

Answer (score 0):

After one relation, you have to give other property groups an alias and bind them to the model...

```
$this->Character->bindModel('PropertyGroup2', array('className' => 'PropertyGroup'));
```

Then you reference them as PropertyGroup and PropertyGroup2.

If you need the multiple property groups in many situations, the just bind the PropertyGroup2 in your hasMany array and be sure to set the classMame so it referenced the PropertyGroup class.